# how to give link for a php code?

Tags: php

I need to give a link for a php code

```
'label' => $this->__('Best Sellers')
```

For the above link

I tried giving like this

```
echo  <a href="http://new-design.html> $this->__('New Design') </a>
```

but it didnt work

Comment: what is "a link for a php code"?

Comment: You need to concatenate the strings with the `.` operator. (With echo, you could also provide multiple arguments, separated by `,`)

Comment: You want to use PHP in a .html file?

Comment: this might help you for better understand echo http://us.php.net/echo

Answer (score 4):

It should be

```
echo "<a href='new-design.html'>".$this->__('New Design')."</a>";
```

You were missing the `.` for PHP string concatenation ([Look at this link for more info](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php))

You were also missing a closing `>` for the `a` element.

Please note that this:

```
$this->__('Text here')
```

is only available in certain frameworks and won't work in *normal* php. If this doesn't work, try this:

```
echo "<a href='new-design.html'>New Design</a>";
```